# Rails SideKiq - WARN: NotImplementedError: NotImplementedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sidekiq

I have the following model method to send a welcome Email after account has been confirmed

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable


  # Methods

  # Override devise after_confirmation
  def after_confirmation
    welcome_email
    super
  end


  # Private Methods
  private

  def welcome_email
    # Brands::MemberMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_now
    p self.inspect
    EmailJob.perform_later(self)
  end

end
```

This is my Job `app/jobs/email_job.rb`

```
class EmailJob < ActiveJob::Base
  # Set the Queue as Default
  queue_as :default

  def perform(member)
    Brands::MemberMailer.welcome_email(member).deliver_now
  end
end
```

When i confirm the account the sidekiq gets delegated but am getting the following error

```
2016-04-14T07:23:33.898Z 2584 TID-ox0d7xt8s EmailJob JID-6bff3e6c3f92f7fea682a97e INFO: start
2016-04-14T07:23:34.033Z 2584 TID-ox0d7xt8s EmailJob JID-6bff3e6c3f92f7fea682a97e INFO: fail: 0.135 sec
2016-04-14T07:23:34.033Z 2584 TID-ox0d7xt8s WARN: {"class"=>"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper", "wrapped"=>"EmailJob", "queue"=>"default", "args"=>[{"job_class"=>"EmailJob", "job_id"=>"914ac6b3-4d63-4f2e-b1eb-81835799e760", "queue_name"=>"default", "arguments"=>[{"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://skreem/Member/3"}], "locale"=>"en"}], "retry"=>true, "jid"=>"6bff3e6c3f92f7fea682a97e", "created_at"=>1460618613.89504, "enqueued_at"=>1460618613.895284, "error_message"=>"NotImplementedError", "error_class"=>"NotImplementedError", "failed_at"=>1460618614.027425, "retry_count"=>0}
2016-04-14T07:23:34.033Z 2584 TID-ox0d7xt8s WARN: NotImplementedError: NotImplementedError
2016-04-14T07:23:34.033Z 2584 TID-ox0d7xt8s WARN: /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:39:in `perform'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:32:in `block in perform_now'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:46:in `perform'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/active_job.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:257:in `with_locale'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/translation.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:498:in `block (2 levels) in around'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:343:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/logging.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `instance_exec'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:342:in `block in simple'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:497:in `block in around'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_perform_callbacks'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:31:in `perform_now'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.5.2/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb:42:in `perform'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:151:in `execute_job'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:127:in `block in invoke'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sidekiq.rb:33:in `block in call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:362:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.15.0.314/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/sidekiq.rb:29:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:31:in `with_context'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:129:in `block in invoke'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `call'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:132:in `invoke'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:128:in `block in process'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:167:in `stats'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:127:in `process'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:79:in `process_one'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:67:in `run'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:16:in `watchdog'
/Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sidekiq-4.1.1/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:24:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Comment: `include Sidekiq::Worker` - can you try adding this to your `EmailJob` and remove `queue_as :default` option. As sidekiq by default set default queue.

Comment: @dkp You cannot include Sidekiq::Worker in an ActiveJob: EmailJob

Comment: yes, i did not notice that at first glance. have you added `ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` ?

Comment: @dkp yes have set it in the initializer

Comment: @HarshaMV Were you able to fix this issue?
If yes then can you share how?